# How do i get a variable from within a script tag using python and selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm trying to get data for graphs and have found that the data is stored within the script tag. There are numerous other script tags before this and i'd like to access var line1 to get the dates and values. Is this possible?

This is the html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $J(document).ready(function(){
    var line1=[["Dec 15 2013 01: +0",46,"1"],["May 26 2020 22: +0",31.883,"1"]];
    g_timePriceHistoryEarliest = new Date();
    if ( line1 != false )
    {
        g_timePriceHistoryEarliest = new Date(line1[0][0]);
        g_timePriceHistoryLatest = new Date(line1[line1.length-1][0]);
    }

    var strFormatPrefix = "$";
    var strFormatSuffix = "";

    g_plotPriceHistory = CreatePriceHistoryGraph( line1, 7, strFormatPrefix, strFormatSuffix );

    pricehistory_zoomMonthOrLifetime( g_plotPriceHistory, g_timePriceHistoryEarliest, g_timePriceHistoryLatest );
});
</script>
```

I've tried

```
script = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("script")
scriptText = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerHTML", script)
print(scriptText)
```

but scriptText returns empty

The full xpath is

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[7]/div[2]/script[2]/text()
```

Would appreciate any help! Thanks!

Solved:

```
import urllib.request
import re
url=urllib.request.urlopen("yourURL")
content=url.read()
html = content.decode('utf-8')
var_re = re.compile(r'var line1=\[(.+)\]')
date_match = var_re.findall(html)
print (date_match)
```

Comment: Could you please try the below code.

scriptText = str(driver.execute_script("return line1;"))

Comment: I do not have much knowledge of python syntax. So I believe that by returning the variable itself you maybe able to access the same.

Comment: Have been trying to return the variable but it's been saying line1 is undefined, the answer provided below works though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data you want to extract is in the HTML itself you don't need to use selenium.  You can use the `requests` library and `re` library to extract it directly from the HTML.  Here's the regex code for extracting the data from the sample HTML that you provided.  It returns a list of `str` with the dates and values you seem to want.

Since you didn't provide the URL you'll need to code the `requests` portion yourself.

```
html = """<script type="text/javascript">
$J(document).ready(function(){
var line1=[["Dec 15 2013 01: +0",46,"1"],["May 26 2020 22: +0",31.883,"1"]];
g_timePriceHistoryEarliest = new Date();
if ( line1 != false )
{
    g_timePriceHistoryEarliest = new Date(line1[0][0]);
    g_timePriceHistoryLatest = new Date(line1[line1.length-1][0]);
}

var strFormatPrefix = "$";
var strFormatSuffix = "";

g_plotPriceHistory = CreatePriceHistoryGraph( line1, 7, strFormatPrefix, strFormatSuffix );

pricehistory_zoomMonthOrLifetime( g_plotPriceHistory, g_timePriceHistoryEarliest, g_timePriceHistoryLatest );
});</script>"""

var_re = re.compile(r'var line1=\[(.+)\]')
date_match = var_re.findall(html)

print(date_match)

Output:
['["Dec 15 2013 01: +0",46,"1"],["May 26 2020 22: +0",31.883,"1"]']
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! have edited the question to add the code i used!